# Basic String Issue

Tags: java, string, textfield

Ok, so here I have a textbox, and whatever the user types is the string "input1"

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GMN extends JFrame
{
    public static String input1 = "";
    JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
    JLabel jl1 = new JLabel();
    JLabel jl2 = new JLabel();
    JLabel jl3 = new JLabel();
    JTextField jt1 = new JTextField(45);

    public GMN()
    {

        String compChoiceText = "Comp Choice:";
        String compChoice = compChoiceText+" 0";
        String yourChoiceText = "Your Choice: ";
        //String inputYou = jt1.getText();
        String yourChoice = yourChoiceText + input1;



        setTitle("Guess My Number!");
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(1200, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jp1.add(jt1);
        jl2.setText(compChoice);
        jl3.setText(yourChoice);

        jt1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                input1 = jt1.getText();
                //jl1.setText(input1);
                jl3.revalidate();
            }
        });//ending of actionlistener for textfield
        jp1.add(jl3);
        jp1.add(jl2);
        //jp1.add(jl1);
        add(jp1);
        System.out.println(jt1.getText());
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GMN gmn = new GMN();
        System.out.println(gmn.input1);
        //String input1 = gmn.input1;

    }
}
```

After this I want to display it as a label, but also need to set it as a string where my whole program can use it, and if anyone is very good, is there a way to make it where it gets the text as a int instead of a string. It seems when I call the string input1, its bringing up null because its not reading what the user inputted but its not null in the jl1(label), as it says what the user typed. I don't understand why the jl1 can read it but a string outside of the actionperformed cant.

Where I call it (outside of actionevent)

```
    String yourChoiceText = "Your Choice:";
    String yourChoice = yourChoiceText + input1;
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(String s)`

Comment: use jl1.getText(); to retrieve input.. or use a static variable somewhere to hold the value.

Comment: you want to have "Your Choice:" as an int?
I wouldn't recommend Integer.parseInt then, because that String is not a numeric value.
to set it in the label, why would you not put that in the actionPerformed, since that is when you want to set it?

Comment: I tried doing that but the value stays blank like its not reading it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save it as a class variable like this:

```
class myClass{
    public static String input1 = "";   <--- EDIT
    //Rest of code
}
```

You can access this by `myClass.input1`. And for the int value use:

```
Integer.parseInt(input1)
```